# Using Sed for windows but I keep getting "No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, sed

I downloaded [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) on Windows 8.0

As my first try, on the command line I ran

sed s/luke.tan@mycompany.com/@mycompany.com/ d:\data\log.txt > test.log

(I am trying as a first cut to anonymize my IIS logs to remove the string before @ in the email by trying on a specific email string)

But I keep getting

sed: can't read d:\data\log.txt : No such file or directory

**Latest update** - I got it to work, very embarrassing mistake. Sorry to waste your time. How do I close this question?

Comment: I think You have to mention the directory as D:\data\log.txt. But I am not sure.

Comment: @Luke Tan You can answer then accept your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a simple typo. Sorry for the trouble.